# Como implementar diferentes clicks para cada item no RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um app, e nele tem `recyclerView` conjugado com `CardView`.
E todas as informações estão armazenadas dentro do próprio app para ser apresentado na `recyclerView`.
Uma parte da estrutura é essa:

```
Album a = new Album("True Romance", 13, covers[0]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Xscpae", 8, covers[1]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Maroon 5", 11, covers[2]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Born to Die", 12, covers[3]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Honeymoon", 14, covers[4]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("I Need a Doctor", 1, covers[5]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Loud", 11, covers[6]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Legend", 14, covers[7]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Hello", 11, covers[8]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Greatest Hits", 17, covers[9]);
        albumList.add(a);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

E o onClick vem logo em seguida:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(  
    new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        // TODO Handle item click
      }
    })
);
```

Como faço para adaptar cada item com um click diferente?
Por exemplo:

> Clicou no "True Romance" ir para uma nova atividade, "Xscpae" ir para outra atividade...

Qual é a lógica? Eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Qual é a necessidade de ir para uma tela diferente? Não seria mais fácil ter uma única tela que recebe os dados e depois lá valoriza os textos e etc com os dados? Caso a tela precise de fato ser diferente, você ainda pode passar um parametro no onclick e ir para uma tela fixa e nessa tela você lê esse parametro e dá um setContentView num layout diferente para cada parametro diferente. Mas eu indico a primeira opção.

Comment: Olá, obrigado por responder.
Neste caso, as informações básicas são exibidas neste recyclerView.
Realmente eu preciso enviar para uma nova tela, pois lá terá interações diferentes. Nada fixo.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é ter acesso ao objeto clicado, dada a sua posição no método `onItemClick`.

Você pode criar um método para isso no adapter que está associado com seu RecyclerView, por exemplo, assumindo que no seu adapter você salvou a lista de albuns em uma variável chamada `albumList`:

```
public Album getItem(int position) {
  return albumList.get(position);
}
```

Então no seu método onItemClick, basta recuperar e implementar a ação da melhor forma para cada album:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(  
    new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Album selectedAlbum = adapter.getItem(position);
        // Faca algo com o album
      }
    })
);
```